# How to access remote file in GGIR package in R?

Tags: r, accelerometer

I a using `GGIR` package for accelerometer data analysis. My data is onedrive folder which takes a long time to download. Is there a way I can access the onedrive files directly without downloading to my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this is not possible. If you're working with Azure there are tools available to connect to OneDrive and download/upload the data which is then processed on a separate instance. I'm guessing the same applies to your local machine, but I'm not intimately familiar with Microsoft's services to be sure.

For example:

> By using Azure Logic Apps and the OneDrive connector, you can create automated tasks and workflows to manage your files, including upload, get, delete files, and more. With OneDrive, you can perform these tasks:
>
> - Build your workflow by storing files in OneDrive, or update existing files in OneDrive.
> - Use triggers to start your workflow when a file is created or updated within your OneDrive.
> - Use actions to create a file, delete a file, and more. For example, when a new Office 365 email is received with an attachment (a trigger), create a new file in OneDrive (an action).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedrive